# how to determine the sequence number of odd /even numbers using php

Tags: php

how to determine the sequence number of odd /even numbers using php ?

example ,i want output like here

odd numbers (1,3,5,7,9)

output

```
1 = 1
3 = 2
5 = 3
7 = 4
9 = 5
```

even numbers (2,4,6,8,10)

output

```
2=1
4=2
6=3
8=4
10=5
```

how code to make this function in php?

edit/update
if input 1 then output = 1 , if input 3 then output = 2, if input 21 then output= 11, etc,,

Comment: seems like something you could at least make an attempt at

Comment: You will need to use a for loop.

Comment: Can you provide an example? What have you tried so far?

Comment: with your odd numbers if you didn't include 5 would 7 = 3?

Comment: order sequence if odd number 21 then output is 11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try out this 
**php code**

```
<?php
$result = '';
if(isset($_POST['value'])){
    //assign POST variable to $num
    $num = $_POST['value'];
    $count = 0;

    //for even numbers
    if($num % 2 == 0){
           $count = $num/2;
            $result =  "The Number ".$num." is Even on ".$count;
        }else {
            //if you know about sequences and series, you can understand it :P
            $count = (($num-1) / 2)+1;
            $result = "The Number ".$num." is Odd on ".$count;
    }
}
?>
```

**HTML COde**

```
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="value"/>
<input type="submit" value="Check"/><br/>
<?php echo $result;?>
</form>
```

It is working correctly :P

Comment: it's a shame help-vampires wont realize that a loop here to get 1 result is quite pointless. if you inputted the number 12,548,756,965,214,554,653 you would have to wait 12,548,756,965,214,554,653 iterations of the loop before you get your output

Comment: Hey! @Memor-X, you were right, now check it out. I think now what I have done will also give answer of your question too. :)

Comment: that's better. there's also a way where you don't need 2 separate formulas inside an if statement. as you can see [here](https://repl.it/Dc0Z/8) if you add the mod value it'll always make the number even which can then be divided by 2. this way 1 & 2 = 1, 9 & 10 = 5.

Comment: Hmmm... @Memor-X :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$evenLimit = 10;
$oddLimit = 9;
$count = 1;

for ($x = 1; $x <= $oddLimit; $x = $x + 2) {
    echo $x . "=" . $count . "<br>";
    $count++;
}
echo "<br>";
$count = 1;

for ($x = 2; $x <= $evenLimit; $x = $x + 2) {
    echo $x . "=" . $count . "<br>";
    $count++;
} 
?>
```